# How to put an Android Project on Github?

Tags: android, github

I was trying to use Android Studio's in built VCS but was getting some error. I recently learned that it can be done using Git also. Can anyone tell me how to do that ?

Comment: The message tellls you exactly what you have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. `git init` (unless you have already done so)
2. `git config user.name "someone"`
3. `git config user.email "someone@someplace.com"`
4. `git add *`
5. `git commit -m "some init msg"`

Note that the email you use should be the same as the one associated with your GitHub account.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use Tools like SourceTree to configure. It is quite easy to configure and perform git operation using sourceTree.

https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/